# Real Time Chart Generation using epoch.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, epoch.js

I am trying to create a simple real time chart using **epoch.js** which updates itself on a click event.

My code posted below has a total of 3 functions. They are:
1) generate a random value 
2) generate the current date and time in milliseconds. 
3) onclick event that updates chart datapoints.

Though I have datapoints in the right format as required for the chart. I am unable to update it .

Appreciate any help on find out as to why the graph is not working as it should.

```js
///////////////this function generates the date and time in milliseconds//////////
function getTimeValue() {
  var dateBuffer = new Date();
  var Time = dateBuffer.getTime();
  return Time;
}

////////////// this function generates a random value ////////////////////////////
function getRandomValue() {
  var randomValue = Math.random() * 100;
  return randomValue;
}

////////////// this function is used to update the chart values /////////////// 
function updateGraph() {
  var newBarChartData = [{
    label: "Series 1",
    values: [{
      time: getTimeValue(),
      y: getRandomValue()
    }]
  }, ];
  barChartInstance.push(newBarChartData);
}

////////////// real time graph generation////////////////////////////////////////   
var barChartData = [{
  label: "Series 1",
  values: [{
    time: getTimeValue(),
    y: getRandomValue()
  }]
}, ];

var barChartInstance = $('#barChart').epoch({
  type: 'time.bar',
  axes: ['right', 'bottom', 'left'],
  data: barChartData
});
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js">
  </script>
  <script src="http://www.goldhillcoldtouch.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/d3.min.js">
  </script>
  <script src="http://www.goldhillcoldtouch.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/epoch.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.goldhillcoldtouch.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/epoch.min.css">
</head>

<div id="barChart" class="epoch category10" style="width:320px; height: 240px;"></div>
<p id="updateMessage" onclick="updateGraph()">click me to update chart</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are pushing the wrong object to `barChartInstance` when updating the graph. You need to just push the array containing the new data point, instead of pushing the full configuration again.

```
function updateGraph() {
  var newBarChartData = [{time: getTimeValue(), y:getRandomValue()}];

  /* Wrong: don't use the full configuration for an update.
  var newBarChartData = [{
    label: "Series 1",
    values: [{
      time: getTimeValue(),
      y: getRandomValue()
    }]
  }, ];
  */
  barChartInstance.push(newBarChartData);
}
```

```js
///////////////this function generates the date and time in milliseconds//////////
function getTimeValue() {
  var dateBuffer = new Date();
  var Time = dateBuffer.getTime();
  return Time;
}

////////////// this function generates a random value ////////////////////////////
function getRandomValue() {
  var randomValue = Math.random() * 100;
  return randomValue;
}

////////////// this function is used to update the chart values /////////////// 
function updateGraph() {
  var newBarChartData = [{time: getTimeValue(), y:getRandomValue()}];

  /*
  var newBarChartData = [{
    label: "Series 1",
    values: [{
      time: getTimeValue(),
      y: getRandomValue()
    }]
  }, ];
  */
  barChartInstance.push(newBarChartData);
}

////////////// real time graph generation////////////////////////////////////////   
var barChartData = [{
  label: "Series 1",
  values: [{
    time: getTimeValue(),
    y: getRandomValue()
  }]
}, ];

var barChartInstance = $('#barChart').epoch({
  type: 'time.bar',
  axes: ['right', 'bottom', 'left'],
  data: barChartData
});
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js">
  </script>
  <script src="http://www.goldhillcoldtouch.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/d3.min.js">
  </script>
  <script src="http://www.goldhillcoldtouch.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/epoch.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.goldhillcoldtouch.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/epoch.min.css">
</head>

<div id="barChart" class="epoch category10" style="width:320px; height: 240px;"></div>
<p id="updateMessage" onclick="updateGraph()">click me to update chart</p>
```